# How can i get all buy and sell transactions for an NFT using blockfrost?

Tags: nft, blockfrost, transaction-history

So I want to use blockfrost to extract all transactions of an NFT that are associated with marketplace trades. I understand that I can get an assets transaction history through /assets/{asset}/history but this doesn't quite solve the problem of identifying which transactions were part of a trade on an NFT market place.

Does anyone have a solution? I am doing this as I want to track the history of an NFT to identify / flag stolen NFTs on their journey through the blockchain.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

A marketplace is generally just a contract.

As an example, jpg.store contract hash according to [cexplorer.org](https://cexplorer.io/dapps) is `9068a7a3f008803edac87af1619860f2cdcde40c26987325ace138ad`.

So, if you want to see all transactions regarding to trades, you just have to look at the transactions associated with this script addresses.